# pegar dados da url utilizando javaScript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

Tenho uma url com os dados codificados utilizando encodeURIComponent. Depois eu a decodifico utilizando decodeURIComponent e fica assim:

> http://localhost:8081/editar.html
>        [{
>         "nome": "Darth Vader",
>         "ladoForca": "Negro",
>         "especie": "Humano",
>         "planeta": {
>             "nome": "Tatooine",
>             "regiao": "Sea of Dune e Judland Wastes"
>         }
>        }]

como faço para acessar os valores?

Answer (score 0):

Olha eu tenho um código uma parte dele é essa, eu utilizo o slice para retirar

```
var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
                        var hashes = retorno.split('&');
                                if(hashes.length > 2){
                                    for(var i = 0;i < hashes.length; i++){

                                    var titulo = decodeURI(getUrlTitulo(retorno)[i]);

                                    for(z=0;z < titulo.length;z++){
                                        titulo = titulo.replace("_"," ");
                                    }
```

ps: isso é uma parte, a parte que pega a url, caso queira ele inteiro posso te mandar

Comment: mas como chega sua url? na minha nao tem &

Comment: perdão a demora, irei mandar como está minha url, o parametro & é só alterar , mas ire mandar como chega a url .. acabei de verificar , ele está retornando atualmente como uma variável mesmo, porem a url ficaria concatenada assim .... id_sedex = "1"&cod_sedex = "123456789"&desc_sedex = "Teste de select java"&destino_sedex = "Rua nao faco a minima "&localatual_sedex = "Aonde judas perdeu as botas"

Comment: http://localhost/app2/www/?src=123456789&select=1 uma outra maneira é assim ...